# spark s3 shuffle service failing to fetch blocks

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am using the spark [s3 shuffle service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/introducing-the-cloud-shuffle-storage-plugin-for-apache-spark/) from AWS on a spark standalone cluster

spark version = 3.3.0

java  version = 1.8 corretto

The following two options have been added to my spark submit

```
spark.shuffle.sort.io.plugin.class=com.amazonaws.spark.shuffle.io.cloud.ChopperPlugin \
spark.shuffle.storage.path=s3a://<bucket>/shuffle.tmp \
```

However, when running jobs, I see the following errors on my executors

```
23/01/02 13:27:23 ERROR ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Failed to get block(s) from <IP>:<port>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/spark/spark-ccfc4d1a-ed5f-4510-8045-ab33bf7de2c1/executor-e867d208-4235-4d87-a05d-35abc431794f/blockmgr-a4c2d1c9-399d-482b-b1bb-0112caba7d88/32/shuffle_0_19_0.index
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:582)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocalBlockData(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.$anonfun$receive$8(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.$anonfun$receive$8$adapted(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:246)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofInt.map(ArrayOps.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.$anonfun$receive$7(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.$anonfun$receive$7$adapted(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:290)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:198)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the plugin to the path as well:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/lib/spark/jars/chopper-plugin-3.3-amzn-LATEST.jar \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/lib/spark/jars/chopper-plugin-3.3-amzn-LATEST.jar
```

For TeraSort it could look like this:

```bash
spark-submit \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    \
        ${YOUR_CLUSTER_CONFIG} \
    \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem  \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=${S3A_ACCESS_KEY}  \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=${S3A_SECRET_KEY}  \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=${S3A_ENDPOINT} \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true  \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload=true  \
    --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.block.size=33554432  \
     \
     \
     \
    --conf spark.shuffle.sort.io.plugin.class=com.amazonaws.spark.shuffle.io.cloud.ChopperPlugin  \
    --conf spark.shuffle.storage.path=s3a://${SHUFFLE_PATH} \
    --conf spark.shuffle.storage.s3.enableServerSideEncryption=false  \
    --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/spark/jars/chopper-plugin-3.3-amzn-LATEST.jar  \
    --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/spark/jars/chopper-plugin-3.3-amzn-LATEST.jar  \
    \
    \
    \
    --class com.github.ehiggs.spark.terasort.TeraSort  \
    local:///workloads/terasort.jar s3a://${TERASORT_BUCKET}/${SIZE} s3a://${OUTPUT_BUCKET}/${SIZE}-sorted
```

Edit: Also make sure that `chopper-plugin-3.3-amzn-LATEST.jar` is readable by Spark.